# How do I get a barplot from a dataset?

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have this package called `gapminder`.

I am trying to do this

a.  A bar chart showing the life expectancy for the United States over the years. (Data source: gapminder)

Make a barchart showing the life expectancy of the United States over the years. But I am not entirely sure how to do this.

Can anybody show me how to do this I did `names(gapminder)` and I get:

```
"country"   "continent" "year"      "lifeExp"   "pop"       "gdpPercap"
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow.  People did the work for you (and you should accept the answer) but normally you are expected to show that you have made an effort to figure things out yourself before posting a question.  For example you should have read ?barplot  to learn how to make the bar plot. Then if you showed the code that wasn't working people would help.  That's probably why you have a down vote.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `barplot()` function after transforming your data with `table()`.
For some example, look [here](https://www.statmethods.net/graphs/bar.html).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to subset (select the part of the data you want to use), then you can plot. I spritzed up the plot a bit, it wasn't terribly readable in default form.

```
library(gapminder)

# this selects all the rows where the column 'country' says 'United States'
us <- gapminder[gapminder$country == "United States", ]

# the first argument is the life expectancy values
# I subtract 65 to make the difference between the various years more apparent
barplot(us$lifeExp - 65, names.arg=us$year, main="US life expectancy", 
  xlab="Year", ylab="Age", axes=FALSE)
axis(2, at=0:15, labels=65:80, cex.axis=0.8)
abline(h=0:15, col="#00000044", lty=2)
```

[image]